# Semantic-ui dropdown is not working

Tags: jquery, html, semantic-ui

I have a trouble integrating a dropdown menu in my HTML form. I've tried everything I can do and what I found online but it still doesn't work. I found that this code runs properly on JSFiddle. The script paths are fine and the scripts are loaded correctly.

Did I miss something?

```
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link href="../semantic/packaged/css/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../semantic/packaged/javascript/semantic.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form class="ui form segment" style="width:400px; margin:auto;" method="POST" action="register_do.php">
    <div class="field">
      <label>학년</label>
      <div class="ui fluid dropdown selection">
        <input type="hidden" name="grade">
        <div class="default text">학년</div>
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="item" data-value="10">고1</div>
          <div class="item" data-value="11">고2</div>
          <div class="item" data-value="12">고3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui buttons">
              <button class="ui red submit button">등록</button>
              <div class="or"></div>
              <div class="ui button" onClick="history.back();">취소</div>
          </div>
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it works on Fiddle, but not on your own enviro, check your paths to your script sources.

Comment: may be one of js file reference is not getting picked up properly in your code.

Comment: @briansol Script paths are fine. It is loaded correctly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try putting

```
<script>
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
</script>
```

right before the closing `</body>` tag. You're running the dropdown script before these elements `$('.ui.dropdown')` even exist in the DOM so there's nothing to attach to.

Comment: I hate when `jQuery` silently runs actions on no elements

Comment: You can also do `$(function(){ $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown(); })` and leaving it in the head

Comment: I've also tried `$(document).ready(function() {...});` and leaved it in the head but did not work. What's the problem here?

Comment: @R4T1N4 It seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/o8r0fzfg/ Notice that my fiddle does say load the JavaScript from the head. The one you mentioned in your question was probably loading it `onload`

Comment: This solved all my issues for the past 30 mins. I was using a dropdown in my header menu template and couldn't get it to work, but I put this down in my footer template and now dropdowns work everywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try writing it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
});
```

Your script is on top of the body tag, so you have to check if the DOM is ready. ready() function will check if the DOM is ready first and then run the script.

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs if you use a custom theme for the menu element under collections in the `theme.config` but do not provide an actual override file for variables and overrides in your theme folder - even as empty files.
There is no js error shown up but the dropdown is not working. Make sure you have either all override files provided or replace only the elements you really want to use from your custom theme in `theme.config`.