# Semantic UI dropdown in ASP.Net MVC is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dropdown, semantic-ui

Dropdown is not showing when clicked. Other input fields are working as expected except this. 
The dropdown field is one of the field in form tag.

```html
<div class="field">
    <div class="ui selection dropdown">
        <input type="hidden" name="gender">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="default text">Select Gender</div>
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="item" data-value="0">Male</div>
            <div class="item" data-value="1">Female</div>
            <div class="item" data-value="2">Other</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've initialized it in the script tag just before the end of body tag. Also tried to put in head tag, or added document.ready as well as window.onload but all doesn't fix the problem.

```
<script>
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
</script>
```

FYI, I've installed Semantic-UI ASP.NET MVC in Nuget.

I've tried the solutions below but to no avail.

[Semantic-ui dropdown is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529467/semantic-ui-dropdown-is-not-working)

[Semantic UI Dropdown is not showing the drop down but everything else is working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551424/semantic-ui-dropdown-is-not-showing-the-drop-down-but-everything-else-is-working)

Comment: What does your javascript look like?

Comment: @VtoCorleone I've added the script tag in above.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the drop down list shown now, by adding this script in the head tag.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#divDropdown').click(function () {
            var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
            if (clicks) {
                $('#divDropdown').removeClass('active visible');
                $('#dropdownMenu').removeClass('visible');
            } else  {
                $('#divDropdown').addClass('active visible');
                $('#dropdownMenu').addClass('visible');
            }
            $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
        });
    });
</script>
```

By right, it can be as simple that initializing it with .dropdown should work. But somehow it's not.

I'm still waiting for someone to propose a better solution than this. 
Thanks.

Comment: The reason the above solution works is that the code is waiting for the DOM to load before executing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Include semantic CSS inside the head tag
2. Include jquery in the end of your body tag, then include semantic UI JS
3. Put your code from semantic dropdown inside
   `$(document).ready(function () { //code goes here });`
   this way it will be executed after everything loads (jquery and semantic) and it will work.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

        <title>Test semantic</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic2/semantic.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="field">
            <div class="ui selection dropdown">
                <input type="hidden" name="gender">
                <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                <div class="default text">Select Gender</div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <div class="item" data-value="0">Male</div>
                    <div class="item" data-value="1">Female</div>
                    <div class="item" data-value="2">Other</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="semantic2/semantic.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```